# Is there anything special of the struct of a linked list against a common struct in the storage?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

In a common struct , the size of a struct equals the sum of size of all its members, however when I want to apply this for the linked list based on struct ,it does not hold.

I run the following code on a 64-bit windows system, and my complier is gcc

```
typedef struct node {

    int val;
    struct node *head;
} node_t;

typedef struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
} point_t ;

int main(){

    point_t a = {1,1};
    node_t b={1,NULL};

    printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof(node_t),sizeof(b.head),sizeof(b.val));
    printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(point_t),sizeof(a.x),sizeof(a.y));
}
```

the output turns out to be

```
16 8 4
8  4 4
```

what I expect is that sum of `sizeof(b.val)` and `sizeof(b.head)` should euqual `sizeof(node_t)` just as what happens for `sizeof(point_t),sizeof(a.x),sizeof(a.y)`.

so is there anything special of the struct that forms a linked list in the storage?

Comment: Aside: `sizeof` results in a type of `size_t`.  Use `"%zu"` to match.  `"%d"` wont always work.

Answer (score 0):

hhh I come to answer my own question 5 min later.

reason for this is  Data alignment.To take it simplily, in a struct ,storage that equals the size of the largest data will be allocated for each member

In this question,the `sizeof(node_t.val)` is 4 ,yet 8 is allocated for it(without changing its size) because the largest data type in this struct is `struct node*`,of which size is 8.

Comment: *"storage that equals the size of the largest data will be allocated for each member"* - that's simply not universally true. According to that logic, adding an `int x;` member *before* member `int val;` in your `struct node` would increase the overall struct side by 8 bytes. Try it. You will likely be surprised. Alignment logic and rules are deeper than you're assuming them to be.